# How to edit junit test reports

Tags: jenkins, junit

How can I edit the junit test report that Jenkins generates? I want to edit how the tests are displayed. I want to edit the html report? How can I do that?

For example, the test generates a report with several columns and rows. I want to add a separate section to each report to differentiate test cases based on whether they are actual bugs or not.

Comment: I am after the same answer, did you get some answer for this?